# In IOS6 Simulator ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() always returns kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized

Tags: ios6, abaddressbook

This is the same question as [ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus in simulator always returns kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12602984/abaddressbookgetauthorizationstatus-in-simulator-always-returns-kabauthorization) but that answer did not work for me and I don't have enough reputation to comment on that thread :(

In the IOS6 Simulator `ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus()` always returns `kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized`.  I am looking for a way to "reset" the simulator so I can get it to ask the user "
I've tried resetting with

1. "Reset Location & Privacy" within Setting->General->Reset and
2. reset then entire simulator from the OSX menu IOS Simulator->Reset Content and Settings

I still always get authorized

```
if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
    // I get in here every time
else
    // I NEVER get here, but I should
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like `simulator` always returns granted, so no permission request is needed, and reseting wouldn't help either.

On real devices you can first get "`Not Determined`", and then a permanent "`Denied`" or "`Authorized`", until the user goes to `Settings > general > reset > reset location & privacy`.

Comment: As of now (iOS Simulator Version 7.1 (463.9.41)) this works in the simulator as well.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a dumb question but have you tried resetting the per-app privacy settings in the simulator?

(They are at: Settings.app / Privacy / Contacts / your-app-here )

Comment: Thanks for the idea but I don't have any apps listed there.