# Reset access to contacts in iOS simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios6, ios-simulator

I want to test out the contact authorization process, but the simulator doesn't ask me for permission anymore. I've tried resetting privacy settings, I've tried resetting the simulator completely, I've tried deleting the app, but no matter what, it never asks me for permission. It just assumes I've granted it.

I'm running iOS 6 simulator. There are a couple [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12602984/abaddressbookgetauthorizationstatus-in-simulator-always-returns-kabauthorization) like this on SO, but surprisingly no decent answers. Is there really no way to do this?

Comment: Look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33940858/1415713

Answer (score 44):

Starting with iOS 7, go to Settings, General, Reset and tap Reset Location & Privacy

Comment: I confirmed that this answer is valid for iOS 9 Simulator as well. My app throws up a system alert that "App would like to access photos". I was able to reset this alert's state using the above instructions (i.e make it so the alert is thrown again).

Comment: I was able to reset permissions for the iOS 8.1 simulator by going to Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings in the simulator menu. Reset Location & Privacy did not seem to work for me.

Comment: This doesn't work on simulators where this option doesn't exist but if you switch to a real device it does the job.

Answer (score 5):

You can now use `xcrun simctl privacy` to control these settings.

Examples:

- `xcrun simctl privacy booted reset all` will reset all supported permissions for all apps installed in the currently booted simulator.
- `xcrun simctl privacy booted revoke contacts com.example.my-app` will deny permission for full contact access for just the given Bundle ID on the currently booted simulator.

See `xcrun simctl help privacy` for more details.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work for simulators, it doesn't recognize them as booted.

Answer (score 3):

These instructions are for Xcode 6.

1. Find the identifier of the simulator whose access settings you want to reset in Xcode's Devices window.
2. Delete `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<device>/data/Library/TCC/TCC.db`
3. Relaunch the simulator. (Device > Restart in the simulator menu)

Comment: This no longer works in Xcode14

Comment: It does work in Xcode 15.2

Answer (score 2):

The reset locations/privacy option ONLY works on a device. It doesn't work in the simulator.

Edit: This is no longer true, see laktak's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this has changed. To reset permissions go to:

Settings > Privacy > Contacts